# How to replace python data frame values and concatenate another string with where condition

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to replace column "Time Period" values & attach other string as shown below.

value: 2017M12
M replace with - and add '-01'
Final result: 2017-12-01

```
Frequency,Time Period,Date
3,2016M12
3,2016M1
3,2016M8
3,2016M7
3,2016M11
3,2016M10

dt['Date'] = dt.loc[dt['Frequency']=='3',replace('Time Period','M','-')]+'-01'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [18]: df.loc[df.Frequency==3,'Date'] = \
             pd.to_datetime(df.loc[df.Frequency==3, 'Time Period'], 
                            format='%YM%m', errors='coerce')

In [19]: df
Out[19]:
   Frequency Time Period       Date
0          3     2016M12 2016-12-01
1          3      2016M1 2016-01-01
2          3      2016M8 2016-08-01
3          3      2016M7 2016-07-01
4          3     2016M11 2016-11-01
5          3     2016M10 2016-10-01

In [20]: df.dtypes
Out[20]:
Frequency               int64
Time Period            object
Date           datetime64[ns]    # <--- NOTE
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) :

```
dt['Date'] =  dt[ dt['Frequency'] ==3]['Time Period'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('M','-')+"-01")
```

output

```
    Frequency   Time Period Date
0   3           2016M12     2016-12-01
1   3           2016M1      2016-1-01
2   3           2016M8      2016-8-01
3   3           2016M7      2016-7-01
4   3           2016M11     2016-11-01
5   3           2016M10     2016-10-01
```

Also you don't need to create an empty columns 'Data', `dt['Date'] =`  will create it automatically

Comment: thanks, I want to use where condition as well like : dt['Frequency']=='3'

Comment: @linus here you go !

Comment: Error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax     dt['Date'] = dt[dt['Time Period'] == '3']]['Time Period'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('M','-')+'-01')

Comment: @linus fixed : )